# Is there any schema about classification of Philosophies?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

I would be very interested in a graphical schema, mapping something like [this list](http://consc.net/taxonomy.html), that would show how various philosophies relate to each other.

Comment: Explain your downvotes please.

Comment: Very vague. There are so many taxonomies as there are philosophical ideas. You did not say what you looking for in a taxonomy. Why your example of taxonomy does not serve you?

Comment: @philosophy lover: I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think you should be editing the original question to add another one. Also, the question you *added* does not fit the format here, it sounds like a poll, and we don't vote here.

Comment: @iphigenie: unfortunately, here on Stack* sites, comments are more to say "you shouldn't have done this". You could instead EDIT the question in a way you judge would be more fit to the community. I'm not asking that question to bother you, its just my little contribution to the list of topics that might interest other poeple. As I am not a very regular Stack* user, well, I may not have asked things in the optimal way :). Thanks for your edit.

Comment: @SkippyFastol I didn't mean you but the person who edited your question before me...

Comment: @iphigenie: no worries :)

Comment: I would like to thank all the people who upvoted my question, as well as those who edited it to make it more interesting!!

Answer (score 6):

[On this website](http://www.aleph.se/andart/archives/2009/10/a_taxonomy_of_philosophy.html) you'll find some graphics for *precisely(!)* your list.

You'll find plenty more using [Google Images](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=taxonomy%20philosophy).